# How to find two points on a line perpendicular to a given line

Tags: unity-game-engine

From this image:

[image]

I have a line P0P1 with both points known. How can I find two points, say Q0 and Q1 on a line perpendicular to P0P1?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are working in 2D. To compute Q0Q1, a perpendicular vector to P0P1, you will need a "temporary" perpendicular vector in the 3D space (either this vector "enters your screen" or "leaves" it). Thanks to this temporary vector, you will be able to get Q0Q1.

```
Vector3 P0 = ... ;
Vector3 P1 = ... ;
Vector3 P0P1 = P1 - P0 ;
Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross( P0.normalized, P0P1.normalized ); // Temporary vector
Vector3 Q0Q1 = Vector3.Cross( cross.normalized, P0P1.normalized );
Vector3 Q0 = (P0 + P1) * 0.5f + cross ;
Vector3 Q1 = (P0 + P1) * 0.5f - cross ;
```

Check the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingVectorArithmetic.html) if you want to understand how the `Vector3.Cross` operation works.